# Regex to Identify university email address (ending in .ac.uk)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a sign up form which is only open to students currently studying at a UK university, so need to ensure the email address they enter ends in .ac.uk.

I have the following JS function but it's not working at all.

```
function valUniEmail()
{

var email = document.getElementById('contactFormEmail');
if (email.innerHTML.match(^[\w!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~-]+(?:\.[\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:\.ac\.uk)$`)
                {
                document.getElementById('tick').style.display = 'display;'
                }
                else
                {
                document.getElementById('cross').style.display = 'none;'
                }


}
```

Any ideas why this might not be working?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I could send directly a POST request to your server to bypass this security. You have to also implement this on your server side script. If you want to do it "right", use this [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/719543/) and use a second match like this `\.ac\.uk$` to check if there is `.ac.uk` at the end.

Comment: The display properties value should be "block" and "none", not "display;" and "none;"

Comment: Don't have access to the server, but I'm not dealing with any computer science students, so don't think they'll manage to bypass it haha. Although, thanks I do appreciate your point about security.

Comment: Using the es6 endsWith(), you can write the if statement as if(email.endsWith('ac.uk')) {}, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote the regexp with `/.../` and escape any `/` chars with `\/` like this:

```js
/^[\w!#$%&'*+\/=?^`{|}~-]+(?:\.[\w!#$%&'*+\/=?`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:ac\.uk)$/
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The function now runs, but whatever email address I enter, even those that should pass the condition, fail it.

Comment: @AndyKaufman It seems like the problem was in the fact that we checked for a `\.` before `ac.uk` at the twice, so an address `test@foo.ac.uk` would pass. I've fixed this in the answer.